# Put in array the result from arsort array with fatser method

Tags: php, arrays

How can I put in array the result from arsort array with faster method ?

I have this :

```
Array
(
    [a] => 32389
    [o] => 25534
)
```

I would like this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => array
        ([0] => 'a', 
         [1] => '32389')

    [2] => array
        ([0] => 'o', 
         [1] => '25534')
)
```

I do this :

```
$words = [];
foreach($words as $key=>$value) {
    $words[] = [$k, $v];
}
```

It works, but after my arsort, I would like if (foreach($words as $key => $value) is the better/faster method to execute this task or if there is an other method/function with php ?

Comment: A simple `foreach ($array as $key=>$value)` could be used after the arsort...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I updated my post

Comment: What does your `$words_extract` array look like?

Comment: if you want numeric array keys, why are you using `['word']` and `['count']` in the sample code?

Comment: @Anant yes I know, but I would like to know the "faster method", example : foreach($objects as $object), foreach($objects as $key=>$value), etc... I know, my question was not really clear

Comment: @Anant Can you edit your post with your answer and I mark up it please

Comment: Yes I know, but there is not exist an other method that foreach($objects as $object) more better and faster ? Not use a foreach but other method/function, I updated my post to explain my question, I hope that my post is clear...

Comment: @Anant thank you for your  answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do:-

```
<?php
$data = Array
(
    'a' => 32389,
    'o' => 25534
);

$new_data = array();
foreach ($data as $key=>$value){ // iterate through your original array
    $new_data[] = array($key,$value); // assign key and value array to new array
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_data); // print new array
?>
```

output:-  https://eval.in/556504

Based on your question this is the best solution (every one else also use same things). Also there is no matter of speed in the above loop working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = [ 'a' => 32389, 'o' => 25534 ];

$b = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $b[] = [$k, $v];
}

print_r($b);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 32389
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => o
            [1] => 25534
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = array('a' => 32389, 'o' => 25534);
$result = array();

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
  $result[] = array($k, $v);
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

[Eval.in](https://eval.in/556503)

Check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nearly there.

```
$words_extract = array(
    'a' => 32389,
    'o' => 25534
);

$words = array();
foreach($words_extract as $k => $v) {
    $words[] = array($k, $v);
}
```